# Is there a way to disable the command line window?

Tags: key-bindings, command-line-window

Often the mechanism to end up in the command line window is a transposition typo `q:` instead of `:q` when I intend to be closing Vim.

You can imagine the frustration at this point because the program state is now such that I have to (more carefully) type TWO more proper `:q` to achieve my goal. Although I do have, and can use a nice easy normal mode chord bind `<s-q>` for `:q`, my muscle memory and habits (using non-augmented vims) lead me to continue to use `:q`, so it is not a full solution.

In an effort to mitigate this situation, I have

```
nnoremap q: <Nop>
```

This works, however, now the `q` has an input delay (due to being bound now) and therefore causes the action of exiting from recording a macro/recording to be latent.

How can I remove my ability to enter the command line window without introducing such consequences?

Comment: `:set timeoutlen=100`...see if that helps

Comment: @BLayer I don't think I would want to do that, wouldn't that reduce my ability to execute any and all other multi-key binds??

Comment: Eh? Why would that be? It just reduces the delay. This is exactly what you'll find in `$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` (and what I use on a daily basis).

Comment: Rather than type `:q` which can be messed up, learn to type `ZZ` and friends `ZX,ZQ` ? (I think I got those right)

Comment: I agree with D. Ben, you may want to change your workflow a bit to avoid the situation and make a new habit. I personally use `<c-w>c`/`:close` instead of using `:q`. I find the commandline-window to be super useful and use it many times though out the day. I think it is up there with `<c-x><c-e>` in bash. Maybe it would be better to just map `q` and use `getchar()`.

Comment: @PeterRincker `q` initiates recordings... can't just clobber its existing functionality. I am open to actually making use of the command line window, but it's hampered by another bind of mine which clobbers its enter key, that's a separate topic that I'll have to figure out. I'm actually also realizing finally that it's probably more likely that hitting `<c-f>` in command line is how I accidentally end up in that mode more.

Comment: I think most carefree way to do what you want would be to use `nnoremap q: <nop>`. I think this would be enough.

Comment: BTW the ZZ is fine but its not the same as :q. :q will prompt if unsaved...

Comment: @StevenLu Because ZZ is the same as :x or :wq - save and quit

Answer (score 1):

I have not found a way to disable the command-line window, but, I have eliminated the need for the `q:` bind of mine, by removing it and changing the rest of my vim config to allow my command-line window to work again as intended.

You could say this is solved by application of the XY problem principle.